# Sql Sum of Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

Is it possible to sum two value that comes from `COUNT(DISTINCT [something])`  ?
I have a table that have near 400 million records in it. This table increases based on user visits
and now I want to get `COUNT(DISTINCT [SpecialUser])` bases on normal query it takes about 5-6 minutes to give the query answer.
Now i was thinking, if is it possible to:

> Save the answer from Yesterday's `COUNT(DISTINCT [SpecialUser])`, name it `total` and then SUM it up with the Today's result to increase query speed?
>   I know its not possible in normal way because of Distinct but is there another solution for it ?

For the reference, here's the complete query:

```
DECLARE @Total_User int 

SELECT @Total_User = COUNT(DISTINCT [SpecialUser]) 
FROM [dbo].[Visit] AS V 
WHERE 
  LEN([SpecialUser]) > 1 

UPDATE [dbo].[Stat] 
SET Total_User=@Total_User 
WHERE ID = 1;
```

Comment: @nyzm: Good catch, however, .NET supports many rdbms.

Comment: @nooob change your avatar man .. check the answer below and try learning more .

Comment: @nooob: you have total 400M rows. But how many unique users you have in that table? I mean result of `SELECT count(DISTINCT user) ...`?

Comment: Consider applying indexes. Consider applying indexes. Consider applying indexes on the field(s) you happen to frequently use this query on. 5-6 minutes of time for 400M records is a bit too much I'd say, unless the fields are not indexed. Check the query plan to see where the bottleneck resides.

Comment: I would say almost exactly what woofmeiw said. Your database perhaps isn't normalized. I don't think indexing will help, it still needs an index scan for DISTINCT.

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric: DISTINCT performance is affected by indexes. Check out http://sqlmag.com/data-access/indexing-sort-performance.

Comment: we have a daily index plan and we analyze most of querys with profiler to check index health. the only problem is this query and it takes about 6 minute with index.

Comment: Could you please show us the complete query? And, if possible, all the indexes on affected tables.

Comment: the query is :
`DECLARE @Total_User int
SELECT  @Total_User= COUNT( DISTINCT [SpecialUser] ) FROM [dbo].[Visit] AS V WHERE LEN( [SpecialUser]) > 1
UPDATE [dbo].[Stat]
SET Total_User=@Total_User
WHERE ID=1;`

Comment: for the indexes we use :
`DBCC DBREINDEX ("Visit", " ", 80);
GO
EXEC sp_updatestats
GO`
This happen on all tables

Comment: Ok, now try the same query without `WHERE LEN([SpecialUser]) > 1` clause and tell us how that works.

Comment: The run time is like 40 sec less but the resualt is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously your problem lies in the database schema/table structure.

I believe that every time a user visit happens, a new record is added to the table. However, you have to get all of the distinct `SpecialUser` fields, which is a different kind of information than you have in your table.

Solution would be writing that information in another table (or using one that you already may have). That table should already *have* those distinct values unique-keyed.

However, if this is not possible right now because of... something, best solution I can remember now (and the one that avoids notorious varchar-indexes) is to add a computed column to your table, persist it, index it and use it in your query.

It should look something like this:

```
IsSpecialUser = CASE WHEN LEN([SpecialUser]) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Full DDL:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Visit 
ADD IsSpecialUser AS (CASE WHEN LEN([SpecialUser]) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) PERSISTED
GO
```

After that, create an index on `dbo.Visit.IsSpecialUser`.
Your query should then look like:

```
SELECT @Total_User = COUNT(DISTINCT [SpecialUser]) 
FROM [dbo].[Visit] AS V 
WHERE IsSpecialUser = 1
```

Comment: Oh i guess that do the tricks , but its a along run time query to alter table i guess. 
im going to test it out on backup db !
thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Store the value in a different table for different days. Otherwise it will always take approximately the time you said.

It may be optimized a little but it wont come down much from the 5-6 minutes. I am assuming you need something faster than that. You may try using something like [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html) if you are not comfortable with storing the number in your database.

**Bottom line : you can't speed up sql builtin functions.**

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Ive done this on other Fields like this :
`DECLARE @LastupdateTime Datetime
DECLARE @TotalVisit bigint
DECLARE @LastTotalVisit bigint
DECLARE @NewTotalVisit bigint
SELECT @LastupdateTime=UpdateDate from [dbo].[Stat]
SELECT @LastTotalVisit=TotalNewsVisit from [dbo].[Stat]
SELECT @TotalVisit= Count(*) From Visit WHERE [VisitDate] >= @LastupdateTime 
set @NewTotalVisit = @TotalVisit + @LastTotalVisit 
UPDATE [dbo].[Stat]
 SET TotalNewsVisit=@NewTotalVisit
WHERE ID=1;`
this query boost speed about 5 minutes on that table.
sadly it only works on field without distinct :(